# code signing 64-bit executables on 32-bit windows?

Tags: 64-bit, certificate, code-signing, 32-bit

I've got a 32-bit Windows 2003 system on which I build both 32-bit and 64-bit executables.

Now I want to add code signing to these executables. As far as I understood this involves purchasing an SSL certificate, and 'installing the certificate' on my system. Is this correct? Cause I don't understand why this system-dependency is necessary (or what it is about a certificate that needs to be 'installed' whatsoever), rather than just having a tool which takes the certificate + an executable and signs it.

Anyway, what is the easiest way to go about this, and can I expect any trouble when signing 64-bit executables on a 32-bit system?

Comment: Use makecert utility. Google for it. You can create FREE certificates.

Comment: @anishane: Thanks, but are these free certificates recognized and accepted by other people? I need this code signing stuff to avoid the 'this executable is from an unknown/untrusted vendor' popup warnings.

Comment: hmm.. that's true. I got carried away by "and 'installing the certificate' on ***my system***"

Answer (score 1):

I explain in detail how to go about this in my blog article [You’ve Got a New Verisign Authenticode Certificate – Now What?](http://helgeklein.com/blog/2012/03/youve-got-a-new-verisign-authenticode-certificate-now-what/)

Comment: Thanks, will look into that! Any idea why these certificates need to be 'installed' on a system-wide level, rather than just being used by signtool to sign executables?

Comment: The certificate need not be installed just for signing. Look at the article (bottom) for the signtool commandline for signing executables.

Comment: A right, that clarifies a lot, thanks. I'm in the process of purchasing a certificate, but for starters I'd like to test with a self-signed certificate first. I found (and followed) several tutorials and explanations, but nothing seems to work. Even after 'successfully' signing my exe (according to signtool), the untrusted vendor warning still pops up. Would you know of any guides that explain this in detail? (I assume the problem is in installing the self-signed certificate so my test system trusts it, but no clue what I'm doing wrong)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Helge's answer, I'd like to point out that, depending on the binary you are signing, you may need a more current operating system and tool set. This mainly holds for kernel mode drivers, but under certain circumstances also for user mode code (e.g. code interfacing with the Windows Security Center).

Answer (score 0):

Buy a code signing certificate. Code signing certificates are different from SSL certificates. You would need to submit documents to verify yourself or your business to the certifying authority.

Follow the instructions from the certifying authority to install the certificate on your machine. It can be 32bit or 64bit. Use the same browser you use to submit the certificate request to receive the certificate.

Export the certificate from the certificate store.

Use the signtool to sign your applicaton. You can use the 32bit signtool to sign 32bit and 64bit applications.

Remember to timestamp your certificate otherwise when the certificate expires your applications might act differently.